Can a non european national hold resident permit in France and Belgium? Will there be a double tax for the income from Belgium in Belgium and France?
Me and my wife are Indian national residing and working in Belgium with individual single permit. I am planning to move to France for work by applying France work and resident permit. Can my wife who will still work in Belgium and hold Belgium single permit can apply dependent resident permit in France ? Her primary accommodation will be still Belgium she will stay in Belgium for 4 days a week and 3 days in France with family. So we will maintain two accomodation. One in France (for our family with 2 kids) and one in Belgium (for her alone). Does it make her to pay double tax? We should be filing a tax as family in France and she will be filing a tax in Belgium as individual? ( As I Will be surrendering my Belgium single permit).

In principle, yes, it's not strictly forbidden but will your wife move to France with you? Can she maintain a Belgian permit if she is not physically residing in the country? Will she still have an address in Belgium and declare it as her main residence to the authorities? My guess is that this could be a bigger issue than the overlap between the two permits. Same question the other way around when the times come to renew your French permit.

She will be staying in both France and Belgium. Four days in Belgium and three days in France, we will have an accommodation in France  and Belgium.... My concern is how the tax system works ? I will be paying tax with France government and my wife would be paying tax with Belgium government. Does she need to pay any tax in France too ?

That's a totally different and mostly unrelated question. I am not sure I can answer but I know that it's even more complicated than that. You first need to determine whether your wife is deemed to live with you and be a French resident for tax purposes. If that's the case, it's not you as an individual who has to file and pay taxes but both of you as a married couple. The part of your common income that comes from Belgium will probably be taxable only in Belgium but you would have to check the tax treaty between France and Belgium.

In any case, you have to file a joint tax return in France with two “parts fiscales” (more if you have kids), there is (usually) no notion of you or your wife paying taxes separately, that's not a useful way to analyze the situation.

So in France we need to file a tax as couple with kids and need to show her Belgium salary as salary from abroad and in Belgium she need to file a tax as an individual ( As I won't be a resident anymore in Belgium) ?. So there will a double tax for her income ?

Not necessarily, a quick reading of the tax treaty suggests you might not need to pay taxes on her Belgian (work) income. I am not sure what you should fill in on the tax return, it would be really useful to talk a tax advisor for that (even if that's not so common in France) or check with the tax authorities. This could work to your advantage, having a wife and kids will markedly reduce the tax rate on your own income.

Where we would find a tax advisor experience with these kind of cross border scenario? Any reference would be helpful... Thank you

I don't really know, as I said it's not as common in France as in some other countries. One way is to contact the tax administration directly (https://www.impots.gouv.fr/accueil). The helpfulness and competence of the people I talked to over the year really varies a lot. Another idea would be some accountant (expert-comptable), maybe in the border area?

To sumarize my comments, you have to consider several questions that are mostly separate, legally and practically. The one you asked is the easiest to answer but not the most important.
Your wife can definitely apply for a French residence permit as a dependent. She won't be asked to give up her Belgian permit immediately nor would it automatically become invalid. The question then becomes if she can meet the requirement to keep and renew both permits in the long term (depending on your own status, the permit she will get in France will only be valid for one year).
On the French side of things, a residence permit as a family member (carte de séjour mention « vie privée et familiale ») requires living together. What that means has been disputed in case law and I cannot tell if what you are planning will meet the requirements but you might have to fight the authorities on that. There are precedents of people whose permit renewal got denied because the spouses were working and maintaining a domicile in different parts of France (without any cross-border issue or questions about multiple permits).
Some préfectures are also notoriously painful to deal with, you wait a long time to get an appointment and they might be tempted to refuse by default and let you fight your way through the court system, even if your situation is technically within the rules. Any peculiarity can become an excuse for them to be hostile. That's what I would be most concerned about in the short term. On the other hand, if the kids reside and are schooled in France, this should definitely help you. The agents are basically required and empowered to evaluate your whole family situation (going all the way to a visit at your home by a city employee) and not merely applying a rule based on the permits you hold or the number of days you spend in the country.
You will also need health insurance for your wife. That's also a requirement for the residence permit.
Tax issues are an entirely different matter, mostly separate from the permit itself. As noted in the comments, it could actually work to your advantage but it's quite complex. Note that it is perfectly possible to be deemed a resident for tax purposes but not for immigration purposes (e.g. the French state wants taxes from you but ultimately considers you haven't been living in the country when comes the time to apply for citizenship).
Finally, the implications for your wife's permanent residence in Belgium or your kids future status may be the most consequential. That's an issue that would best be discussed with a Belgian lawyer with a practice in immigration and citizenship law as decisions you are taking now may have implications several years down the line when she applies for citizenship.

If you want a permit in France, you don't want to argue her main residence is in Belgium. Where would the kids live and go to school? Getting it and having the two permits initially is not a problem but when renewing it, you definitely have to claim that the center of her life is in France. I have no idea about Belgian law on permanent residence and the feasibility of applying for citizenship there after all that.

@VulcanVampire Another angle: What do you need the French residence permit for? Spending most of the time out of the country and visiting only on weekends, she might not run afoul of the rules on short-stays for residents in other EU countries. Will she work from France? Once she is a Belgian citizen, living in France will be much easier for all of you.

Thanks for your insights. That helped me to think in another angle. Say I am not applying the resident permit for my wife in France and she would officially stay in Belgium while me and the kids alone are moving to france.can my kids hold resident permit in both countries. Who can apply tax benefits over them ?

@VulcanVampire It's a bit complicated and going beyond what I am comfortable with. Are you hoping for a path to Belgian citizenship for the kids? As far as taxes are concerned, if you argue with the French tax authorities that your wife is a non-resident, then you will be taxed separately. You can get two parts fiscales for you and the kids (so basically dividing your income by two before computing your taxes). If the four of you are residing in France and filing jointly, you get three parts fiscales but I am not sure about the implications in Belgium.

Thank you very much. I will better check more with a tax expert

@VulcanVampire Two last points to pay attention to. (1) I added a note at the end of the answer on the consequences for permanent residence and citizenship in Belgium. It's important to look into that (maybe ask a separate question or seek advice somewhere), quite apart from the residence permit and tax issues.

(2) In theory, your wife is allowed to spend 90 days out of any 180-day period in France as a resident of Belgium. Technically, she is not allowed to work while she is in France and any day where she was partially present counts (so if she is taking a train to France on Thursday evening and returns to Belgium on Monday morning, that's 5 days, not 3). In practice, you might get away with a little more but be careful.

Is this travel between France and Belgium by train is tracked ? How serious are they monitoring it ?

@VulcanVampire They are not, as far as I know, that's why I think you can get away with a little more but be aware of the rules.
